# How to extract a pattern but fill missing values in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, large-data

I have a large tab delimited file (dummy.vcf) with a column of ';' delimited variables. For example:

```
AF_female=0.00000e+00;non_topmed_AF_female=0.00000e+00;control_AF_female=0.00000e+00
control_AF_female=0.00000e+00;non_topmed_AF_female=0.00000e+00
AF_female=0.00008e+00;non_topmed_AF_female=0.00000e+00
```

I would like to extract the "AF_female=X" string for each row with missing values filled in, so the new file is the same length as the original. For example:

```
AF_female=0.00000e+00  
NA  
AF_female=0.00008e+00
```

I have tried:

```
grep -o ';AF_female=[0-9].[0-9]*..[0-9]*' dummy.vcf
```

However, this does not add rows for when the pattern is not matched.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -F';' '
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i ~ /^AF_female=[0-9]+/){
         val=(val?val OFS $i:$i)
     }
  }
  if(val){
     print val
  }
  else{
     print "NA"
  }
}'  Input_file
```

It should check all present values of `AF_female=digits` in a line and will print `NA` in case it finds NULL matches on a line too.

Output will be as follows.

```
AF_female=0.00000e+00
NA
AF_female=0.00008e+00
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above command now.

```
awk -F';' '                           ##Starting awk program here and setting up field separator as semi-colon here.
{
  val=""                              ##Nullifying value of variable val here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                 ##using a for loop which starts from i=1 to i=NF value. Where NF is number of fields value in current line.
     if($i ~ /^AF_female=[0-9]+/){    ##Checking condition if a field starts from AF_female and then digits then do following.
         val=(val?val OFS $i:$i)      ##Creating variable val whose value is current field value and concatenating its own value.
     }
  }
  if(val!=""){                        ##After coming out of for loop checking if variable val value is NOT NULL then do following.
     print val                        ##Printing value of variable val here.
  }
  else{                               ##Mentioning else of above if condition here.
     print "NA"                       ##Printing NA here.
  }
}' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```